# Flow Send to Slack fails with "Salesforce user isn’t connected to Slack. Reinstall the app in Slack, or reconnect the app’s Salesforce user to Slack"

Tags: visual-workflow, slack

Use case was to create custom notifications (via Screen Flow-associated Quick Action) into a Slack Sales Channel that was already associated to the Account record.

- Running user has all necessary SFDC Slack permissions
- Running user has added `Sales Cloud for Slack` app and `Salesforce for Slack` apps and connected both to SFDC

Flow checks to make sure using Flow Action `Check if Users are Connected to Slack`

- Result is YES

Flow then loops through each Sales Channel (`Swarm`) whose `RelatedToId` matches the screen flow's `recordId`

- Result is 1 Swarm record

A Flow Send Slack Message is executed for the iterator's `Swarm`

### RESULT

`The Salesforce user isn’t connected to Slack. Reinstall the app in Slack, or reconnect the app’s Salesforce user to Slack, and try again`

How can it be that the running user

- already checked to be connected in Slack earlier in the Flow, and
- proven to be able to create Sales Channels in Slack and
- proven that within Slack, they can search and create SFDC records

can't send a message to Slack and SFDC thinks they aren't connected? [image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. *(And if you're like me, you probably spent more time than you wanted on sorting out Slack/SFDC connection/authorization issues, especially across sandboxes and PROD - so you immediately assume it is something fundamental about the connection)*

**Let's dig into the Send to Slack action**

- `Slack App` - set to `Sales Cloud for Slack` (could also be `Salesforce for Slack` or `Service Cloud for Slack` depending on what you have installed.
- `Slack Workspace` - a dropdown and if you're connected, you'll see your Slack workspace(s). For me, this is `MyCompany`
- `Execute Action As` - set to `Slack App` (default)
- `Slack Conversation Id` - this needs to be the Slack channel Id. More on this later.
- `Slack Message` - some text template or constant or formula or .... Can use limited Slack `mrkdwn` for formatting like `_thisWillBeItalics_`
- `Salesforce Record ID` - will be `recordId`

**So, how do you get the `Slack Channel Id` from the `Swarm` (Sales Channel)?**

The  Schema is:

```
CollaborationRoom (parent)
     |
   Swarm (child)
```

The channel Id is found in `CollaborationRoom.PlatformKey`  ([CollaborationRoom ObjectRef](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationroom.htm?q=collaborationroom))

If, you were like me (initially) and set the Send Slack Message action input variable `Slack Conversation Id` to `Swarm.CollaborationRoomId`, the value will look like `9CRVC00000003xB4AQ` and, naively, I thought SFDC would automatically look up the Slack channel Id from the corresponding `CollaborationRoom` parent object. *After all, the Flow builder knew what workspaces and Slack apps I had installed.*

**NOPE**

For the use case where the Slack channel is dynamic (as in Sales Channels), you need to set

`Slack Conversation Id` to `yourSwarmLoopIterator > CollaborationRoom.PlatformKey`

Notes:

- If `Slack Conversation Id` is set to `{$User.Id}`, the Slack message will be sent to the Slack app in your workspace, not to your personal channel
- If you want to send a Slack message as a DM to a Slack user (and not to their `xxx for Slack` app), `Slack Conversation Id` must be set to the Slack user's Id, not the SFDC user's Id. Note [Idea to get directly in Flow](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Q0Eg6UAF/new-flow-action-get-slack-user-id). Various Googling suggests saving the Slack userId as a custom field on SFDC `User` record but the ideal solution is to query the User's personal Settings `Slack User Mappings` *(AFAIK, as of V60 this is not exposed but comment if you know better)*